# Re-use the same ofstream object

Tags: c++, ofstream

I would like to know if its possible to open multiple files with the same ofstream object ?

```
string fileName = "transaction" + to_string(nbFile) + ex;
ofstream fs(fileName.c_str());
fs << "foo";

nbFile++;
fs.close();

string fileName = "transaction" + to_string(nbFile) + ex;
ofstream fs(fileName.c_str());
fs << "foo2"
```

If I execute this code, the second file will to be create. I can't find in the MSDN doc if we can re-open a file using the same ofstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if its possible to open multiple files with the same ofstream object ?

Yes. Here's how:

```
string fileName = "transaction" + to_string(nbFile) + ex;
ofstream fs(fileName.c_str());
fs << "foo";

nbFile++;
fs.close();

fileName = "transaction" + to_string(nbFile) + ex;

// Not this.
// ofstream fs(fileName.c_str());

// This
fs.open(fileName.c_str());

fs << "foo2"
```

Comment: If the file does not exist, does fs.open will create it ?

Comment: @seb, yes it will barring any file system permissions issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [`open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) function of [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) class.

```
fs.open(fileName.c_str());
```